# Where should I ask this question about sending bug reports with C#?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question I would like to ask regarding a way to report bugs from within a C# application. A draft of that question is something along the lines of:

> I'd like to know how I should go about sending bug reports from my C#
> game.
>
> I don't know if there are good bug reporting tools out there, how they
> may work and whether they may be suitable for my needs. What I do know
> is that I'd like to make the bug reporting as easy on the user as
> possible, since it's a game and gamers want to play, not sit around
> describing every little detail about the bug they just encountered.
>
> I'm not expecting too many or too long bug reports, and I guess I
> could be okay receiving them as email, but then I don't know how to
> send emails from C# apps (or without logging into existing email
> accounts).

There are probably several questions here, so I'm asking for some guidance.

Comment: I'm assuming the body of this questions is the question you want to ask on another site?

Comment: If I can successfully determine which question I should be interested in finding answer to, then part of the body of this question is the question I want to ask.

Answer (score 10):

You have to be *very* careful when asking a question of this nature, because it's very easy end up asking a dreaded shopping/recommendation question. You know, like this:

> What is the best bug reporting tool to use for a game written in C#?

We don't do those types of questions on Stack Overflow. We are not a recommendation engine, and we won't abuse the Q&A system to build lists. Questions like that will end up closed as "off-topic" or "too broad".

Instead, you need to ask an actual question about accomplishing a particular goal (e.g., capturing and emailing bug reports from a C# application). Describe your specific requirements *in detail*, making sure to note any caveats, special considerations, and other limitations. Then ask how you can achieve this goal.

It would also be looked on approvingly if you included in the question some of the ideas that you've already had, and possibly some solutions that you've already investigated. People like to see that you've spent some time and invested some effort into solving your problem already. They're much more likely to help you if you show that you are willing to help yourself. More importantly, they're less likely to vote to close your question.

In the process of answering a question like this, people will inevitably make suggestions of third-party products. But that is okay, since there is a clear question being asked and answers can be objectively judged on whether they meet your stated criteria.

The truth is, you don't really *care* to see a list, summary, or comparison of all the different bug reporting tools that are out there. If you wanted that, you could just use Google. But that is just noise. You're looking for a specific solution to solve a specific problem. And that's what Q&A is for.

Related Reading: [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: I'm kind of against using any kind of sophisticated software that may require a ton of my time for setting up and managing, so then my question would include too many "but I don't want that"s and it probably wouldn't look so good. I haven't tried anything yet, because I'm not at the stage where I can start distributing my game. I guess I could go with emailing those bug reports, but I'd also like to know if there is a better and not much more time consuming solution.

Comment: @user1306322: you may want to start in an appropriate chat room to get some ideas. In my opinion, you don't have a Stack Exchange question _yet_, you're more looking for ideas/suggestions.

Comment: It sounds like you're still at your own research stage then @user1306322. I'm not sure there is a good question to formulate just yet.

Comment: Yes, I would recommend starting by doing a bit of preliminary research then, and possibly testing a few of the popular offerings. I could imagine a way to write this question where it would be acceptable, but that's likely the result of my extensive experience with Windows and bugs. :-) I would start by looking at [Windows Error Reporting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb513641.aspx), and perhaps commercial packages like [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/). As mentioned, Google will return many more options to explore. @user1306322

Answer (score 3):

This question, with edits, may be on topic for [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Specifically, **edits should focus on clearly defining criteria** that you're looking for, describing how you envision this tool working, etc.. See [their meta answer](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197/my-instincts-are-all-wrong) on writing good questions.

<sub>This site is an explicit exception to the general "no shopping/recommendations" policy mentioned in the other answer</sub>